# Updating a whole table without locking in MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking

Running this update statement will lock every row in the table for 5 seconds.

```
UPDATE `audio_clips` SET activity = activity * 0.95;
```

Is there a way to do it in batches (internally to mysql), or to perform the statement without locking?

This is a field used to show what is currently popular on the site (like Reddit, Hacker News, etc). Whenever an audio_clip is played, activity is bumped by one. On a regular basis, we 'decay' the activity of each clip. I'm not bothered about updating atomically, as long as every row gets decayed.

Comment: Is the table type MyISAM or InnoDB? Why are you updating all the records or is this just a typo? You're missing WHERE clause in your posted SQL statement.

Comment: InnoDB. I am updating every record because I will sort by the column. I need popular items to go up the list, and items that are no longer popular to go down the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I ended up doing it in batches. It may not be perfectly scalable but in batches of 1000, each record is tied up for about 35ms. The whole process only takes 10 seconds of each hour.

Good enough.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely take a different approach.

Wouldn't it be possible to set a timestamp as the clip is played, and while bumping calculate the decay since that timestamp? When reading out for statistics, you should take the activity minus the decay since the last timestamp.

This way you still need only one update per clip played.

To make it concrete:

```
UPDATE `audio_clips` SET `lastview`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
                   `activity`=1+`activity`*POW(0.9,(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-`lastview`)/3600)
               WHERE `clipid`=$clipid
```

For a decay of 10% per hour and a bump of 1 per view.

To view current stats:

```
SELECT *,`activity`*POW(0.9,(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-`lastview`)/3600) AS `current_activity`
       FROM `audio_clips`
```

Comment: I like this approach, but if I plan to sort by the column, I would still need to do a batch decay of inactive clips, wouldn't I?

Comment: No, you can sort by any expression, also the calculated current activity.

Comment: Hmm. It might need agressive caching as it wouldn't be able to use an index. Does it make a difference if I tell you we're talking about ~350,000 rows?

Comment: Hmm yes. Knowing that, I'd definitely not do the full table update ;-) You'd have to test your caching assumption. But I presume you need the N most active ones, if so you could simply sort by `activity` and take the 2*N most active ones, and then post-process the result to get the true top-N.